# SQL Join data and get rows that don't match with NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables that I want join as follows:

Table 1

```
 Code1 | Code2 |  Date(1)   | Amount(1)     
   A   |   AA  | 201802     |  100         
   A   |   AA  | 201803     |   50     
   A   |   AA  | 201804     |   30
```

Table 2

```
 Code1 | Code2 |  Date(2)  | Amount(2)          
   A   |   AA  | 201801    |   20      
   A   |   AA  | 201802    |   10      
   A   |   AA  | 201803    |   10
```

And I want the resulting table to look like this:

Result

```
 Code1 |  Code2 |  Date(1)   |   Date(2) |  Amount(1) | Amount(2)       
   A   |   AA   |    NULL    |    201801 |    NULL    |   20      
   A   |   AA   |   201802   |    201802 |    100     |   10      
   A   |   AA   |   201803   |    201803 |    50      |   10      
   A   |   AA   |   201804   |    NULL   |    30      |   NULL
```

So  I need to join these two tables 
`on table1.Code1 = table2.Code1 AND table1.Code2 = table2.Code2 AND table1.Date(1) = table2.Date(2)`

But I also want the rows where the dates don't match with a null is the columns related to the non matching table (such as the row for `Date(1) = 201804` in my example).

I have tried joining that two tables with left, right and outer join but I still am not successful in getting the rows with the nulls (probably because Code1 and Code2 don't exist for that particular missing row)

Maybe a cross apply could work, but I am not sure how to execute it.

I want the most efficient way in terms of performance because this is a part of a big query containing lots of data and lots of calculations.

UPDATE:
The code I used is:

```
Select table1.Code 1, table1.Code2, Table1.Date(1), table2.Date(2), table1.Amount(1), table2.amount(2)
FROM Table1
Full Outer Join 
table2 ON 
    table1.Code1 = table2.Code1 
    AND table1.Code2 = table2.Code2 
    AND table1.date(1) = table2.date(2)
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
 Code1 |  Code2 |  Date(1)   |   Date(2) |  Amount(1) | Amount(2)             
   A   |   AA   |   201802   |    201802 |    100     |   10      
   A   |   AA   |   201803   |    201803 |    50      |   10
```

Which is missing these two rows:
 `A   |   AA   |    NULL    |    201801 |    NULL    |   20

  A   |   AA   |   201804   |    NULL   |    30      |   NULL`

Comment: Can you show us your attempts please? It's very difficult (impossible) for us to tell you why the SQL you used didn't work when we don't know what that SQL was.

Comment: At a guess, perhaps you want a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: What if `Code1` or `Code2` does't match?

Comment: Is the issue that for some of the records you are also getting a `NULL` `Code1` and `Code2`, which you don't want? If it is you could use `FULL OUTER JOIN` and in your select, use `ISNULL(table1.Code1, table2.Code1) AS Code1` and `ISNULL(table1.Code2, table2.Code2) AS Code2` to ensure that the Code is taken from the table that has that record.

Comment: Can you please show us your attempt it's will be easier to correct it
i think you want a full outer join

Comment: Code 1 and Code 2 have to match, but the issue is that in some cases there is no row instance for a certain date and I want it to appear with a NULL for value

Comment: With your sample data, the way to get your desired result is indeed using a `full join`.

However, based on your last comments, where you wrote "Code 1 and Code 2 have to match" I'm not sure it is the solution you are looking for - Your sample data does not cover cases where any of these columns doesn't match so we can't know what is the desired output for such a situation.

Comment: [Check out this demo to see what I mean.](https://rextester.com/DUOWI56875)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this.

```
--sample dataset
DECLARE @tab1 as table (
    Code1 varchar(10),
    Code2 varchar(10),
    Date1 int,
    Amount1 int )
insert into @tab1
values
    ('A', 'AA', 201802, 100),
    ('A', 'AA', 201803, 50),
    ('A', 'AA', 201804, 30),
    ('B', 'AA', 201802, 100) --additional

DECLARE @tab2 as table (
    Code1 varchar(10),
    Code2 varchar(10),
    Date2 int,
    Amount2 int )
insert into @tab2
values
    ('A', 'AA', 201802, 100),
    ('A', 'AA', 201803, 50),
    ('A', 'AA', 201801, 30)
```

query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select
        coalesce(table1.Code1,table2.Code1) as Code1,
        coalesce(table1.Code2,table2.Code2) as Code2,
        table1.Date1,
        table2.Date2,
        table1.Amount1,
        table2.amount2
    FROM @tab1 as Table1
        Full Outer Join @tab2 as table2 ON 
            table1.Code1 = table2.Code1
            AND table1.Code2 = table2.Code2
            AND table1.date1= table2.date2
    ) as t1    
     CROSS APPLY ( --to exclude records not matched by "Code 1 and Code 2"
                    SELECT top 1
                        Code1
                    FROM @tab2 as t
                    where t.Code1 = t1.Code1 
                    and t.Code2 = t1.Code2
                ) as c
ORDER BY   t1.Date1
```

or like this:

```
select
    coalesce(table1.Code1,table2.Code1) as Code1,
    coalesce(table1.Code2,table2.Code2) as Code2,
    table1.Date1,
    table2.Date2,
    table1.Amount1,
    table2.amount2
FROM @tab1 as Table1
    Full Outer Join @tab2 as table2 ON 
            table1.Code1 = table2.Code1
        AND table1.Code2 = table2.Code2
        AND table1.date1= table2.date2
where exists (select null --to exclude records not matched by "Code 1 and Code 2"
              from @tab2 as t2
              where coalesce(table1.Code1,table2.Code1) = t2.Code1
                    and coalesce(table1.Code2,table2.Code2) = t2.Code2)
ORDER BY   table1.Date1
```

[image]

Comment: try adding this row to one of the tables: `('B', 'AA', 201802, 100)` and see what happens. Is that the desired results? based on the OP's comment to the question ("Code 1 and Code 2 have to match") probably not.

Comment: I know what the outcome will be, I'm just not sure what the OP wants. I already had the rextester demo ready when you've posted your answer; I'm still waiting for the OP to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated query should work if you ISNULL the CodeX columns.

```
declare @t1 table (Code1 varchar(4), Code2 varchar(4),  Date1 date, Amount1 int)
declare @t2 table (Code1 varchar(4), Code2 varchar(4),  Date2 date, Amount2 int)

insert into @t1
values
   ('A', 'AA', '2018-02-01', 100 ),     
   ('A', 'AA', '2018-03-01', 50 ),     
   ('A', 'AA', '2018-04-01', 30 )

insert into @t2
values
   ('A', 'AA', '2018-01-01', 20 ),     
   ('A', 'AA', '2018-02-01', 10 ),     
   ('A', 'AA', '2018-03-01', 10 )

SELECT 
    code1   
    ,code2  
    ,date1  
    ,date2  
    ,amount1    
    ,amount2
FROM (
    SELECT code1, code2 FROM @t1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT code1, code2 FROM @t2
) t0
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
        date1, date2, amount1, amount2
    FROM @t1 t1  
    FULL OUTER JOIN @t2 t2 ON t1.Code1 = t2.Code1 and t1.Code2 = t2.Code2 and date1 = date2
    WHERE 
        t0.code1 = isnull(t1.Code1, t2.code1)
    and t0.code2 = isnull(t1.Code2, t2.code2)
) tt
ORDER BY 
    date1, date2
```

Comment: try adding this row to one of the tables: `('B', 'AA', '2018-02-01', 100)` and see what happens. Is that the desired results? based on the OP's comment to the question ("Code 1 and Code 2 have to match") probably not.

Comment: Updated query to accommodate for the scope that crept in the comments

Answer (score 0):

My suggested solution involves a full join and another join to a derived table that contains all the combinations of `code1` and `code2` that exists in both tables, using the `intersect` operator.

First, create and populate sample data (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T1 AS TABLE
(
    Code1 char(1),
    Code2 char(2),  
    Date1 char(6),   
    Amount1 int    
)    

DECLARE @T2 AS TABLE
(
    Code1 char(1),
    Code2 char(2),  
    Date2 char(6),
    Amount2 int    
)    

INSERT INTO @T1 (Code1, Code2, Date1, Amount1) VALUES
 ('A', 'AA', '201802', 100)         
,('A', 'AA', '201803',  50)     
,('A', 'AA', '201804',  30)
,('B', 'AA', '201802',  30);  -- Note: Added to the original sample data


INSERT INTO @T2 (Code1, Code2, Date2, Amount2) VALUES  
 ('A', 'AA', '201801', 20)
,('A', 'AA', '201802', 10)      
,('A', 'AA', '201803', 10)
,('A', 'AB', '201802', 10);  -- Note: Added to the original sample data
```

The query:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(T1.Code1, T2.Code1) As Code1,
        ISNULL(T1.Code2, T2.Code2) As Code2,
        Date1, Date2, Amount1, Amount2
FROM @T1 As T1
FULL JOIN @T2 As T2
    ON T1.Code1 = T2.Code1
    AND T1.Code2 = T2.Code2
    AND T1.Date1 = T2.Date2
-- Remove this next join if you want to get rows where codes don't match
JOIN (
    SELECT Code1, Code2
    FROM @T1
    INTERSECT 
    SELECT Code1, Code2
    FROM @T2
) As CommonCodes
    ON CommonCodes.Code1 = ISNULL(T1.Code1, T2.Code1)
    AND CommonCodes.Code2 = ISNULL(T1.Code2, T2.Code2)
ORDER BY Date1
```

Results:

```
Code1   Code2   Date1   Date2   Amount1     Amount2
A       AA      NULL    201801  NULL        20
A       AA      201802  201802  100         10
A       AA      201803  201803  50          10
A       AA      201804  NULL    30          NULL
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/VMKO86533)